# Why is my program given an unexpected token: $end error?

Tags: ruby

Here is my unfinished code:

```rb
#When convert button is pressed
File.rename("*.osz", "*.zip$")

dialog.directory(

    def extract_zip(file, destination) FileUtils.mkdir_p(destination)

    file_path = "./convert_temp/*.zip"
    destination = "./convert_temp/osz/"

    extract_zip(file_path, destination)

until File.exists?( ".osu$" ) == false do
  File.rename("./convert_temp/osz/*.osu$", "*.txt$")
  File.foreach(filename) do |file|

  file_string = File.read('./convert_temp/osz/*.txt$')

  if file_string.include?('Mode: 1')
    puts 'Yes'
  else
    puts 'No'
  end
end
end
```

Robocop giving the following syntax error:

```
unexpected token $end (Using Ruby 2.2 parser; configure using `TargetRubyVersion` parameter, under `AllCops`)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm afraid this code has a few syntax errors, and the scattered indentation isn't helpful. At the very least, you're missing a final `end` keyword and a closing parenthesis, but then you're trying to define a method as a parameter to a function, which doesn't make sense. Can you clarify your intent?

Comment: hello @ggorlen ! Looking back at my code, I now see that I'm missing an end keyword and a closing parenthesis. However, I don't understand what the rest of that sentence means. Could you please explain it in simple person terms so I can learn from it? Thank you so much!!

Comment: No problem. You can't do this: `call_my_function(def MyClass end)` which is essentially what is going on here. The closing parenthesis for `dialog.directory() #<-` needs to be here.

Comment: What is Robocop in this context? I know the movie, but it doesn't seem like you are mentioning that.

Comment: @sawa did I say robocop? my apologies! I meant to say rubocop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, Rubocop is not even able to parse the file, because it has syntax errors.

The error message `syntax error: unexpected token $end` means that the ruby parser was parsing along happily, but then it suddenly encountered an `$end`, which is the parser's way to say "the end of the file". It was expecting more code, but instead it found the end of the file.

This is what your code looks like with proper indentation:

```
#When convert button is pressed
File.rename("*.osz", "*.zip$")

dialog.directory(

  def extract_zip(file, destination) FileUtils.mkdir_p(destination)

    file_path = "./convert_temp/*.zip"
    destination = "./convert_temp/osz/"

    extract_zip(file_path, destination)

    until File.exists?( ".osu$" ) == false do
      File.rename("./convert_temp/osz/*.osu$", "*.txt$")
      File.foreach(filename) do |file|

        file_string = File.read('./convert_temp/osz/*.txt$')

        if file_string.include?('Mode: 1')
          puts 'Yes'
        else
          puts 'No'
        end
      end
    end
```

Using this kind of indentation makes it easy to see that there are some missing ends/parentheses, because the last line is left hanging in the air instead of closing back to the left edge where it started from.

**Additional notes:**

```
dialog.directory(

  def extract_zip(file, destination) FileUtils.mkdir_p(destination)
```

It's very unconventional to define a new method inside a method call. `File.open(def hello_world(..))` Doesn't make a lot of sense.

```
until File.exists?( ".osu$" ) == false do
```

Are you using `$` as a way to indicate "filename ends in .osu"? If yes, it does not work like that. This would look for a file that has `.osu$` as name.

```
  File.foreach(filename) do |file|
```

The `file` parameter is not used in the block that follows, you use `file_string`.

```
    file_string = File.read('./convert_temp/osz/*.txt$')
```

You can't read multiple files at once like that. Also, `File.foreach` above would read the file line by line, so here you are trying to read it again, inside the loop that is reading it already.